# Unable to catch DOMSubtree Modified in youtube Crossrider extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, youtube, crossrider

I am trying to catch on DOMsubtree modified event by using Crossrider extension but unable to get it.

I am trying to get a youtube video url on a page load, upto this it is fine. But when i am trying to click the videos that are on right side article of youtube,youtube is making Ajax type of call to get concerned video then  I am unable to get the clicked video url from addressbar.

Tried with DOMsubtree modified.

```
$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    console.log("something is changing");
});
```

Some tech folks suggested the youtube uses Flash to load video's and Jquery can't predict them. Any suggestions

Comment: I used the code provided in an extension I can see the log messages it produces when the event is triggered, i.e. as the AJAX is loaded. Did you place the code in the _extension.js_ file in the [appAPI.ready](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-ready) method? I'd be happy to take a look if you can provide the extension id with a brief description of the steps you used to reproduce the issue and the browser/OS it was tested on. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. i am getting it but lot of times. i guess appAPI.ready is getting triggered many times. can i know why is that @Shlomo

Comment: appAPI.ready is triggered once, unless you have turned on the (**Settings** >) **Run in Iframes** feature and there are iframes in the page in which case it is run once for each iframe as well. Also bear in mind that the **DOMSubtreeModified** event may be triggered many times if there are multiple updated to the DOM Subtree, which is likely if content is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Completed injecting button on Ajax call via Mutation observer 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = document.querySelector('#player-api'); 
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          if(mutation.type=="attributes"){

            var url1=window.location.href;
            $('#tubevid_div').remove();

              if(url1.indexOf('youtube.com/watch?v=')){
                 InjectUtubeDownloadButton($,url1);
                 //observer.disconnect();
              }
          }

        });    
      });  
   // configuration of the observer:
     var config = {attributes: true}; 
   // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
     observer.observe(target, config);
```

Here i am observing the changes in Player-api div from the mozilla docs for all mutation changes callback will be triggered only one time, I used this to Inject my Download Button using  **InjectUtubeDownloadButton();**